# Make varargs Exception constructor to fill stringstream

Tags: c++, templates, stringstream

Basically I am making Exception class and I want to be able to pass debug details easily, such as this:

```
var error = someFunction();
if(error!=0) {
    throw MyException("someFunction ended with error state #",error,'.');
}
```

This would require the `MyException` class to accept varargs arguments that can be processed by `stringstream`. I have no idea how exactly could I do that, what I imagine is this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
template /* MUCH DEEP MAGIC HERE**/
MyException::MyException(/* MOAR DEEP MAGIC!!! **/) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(/** ITERATE THROUGH MORE MAGIC**/) {
        ss<</**FETCH MAGIC STUFF**/;
    }
    this->message = ss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can abuse the comma operator when expanding the parameter pack to do this. Here be that magic.

```
template<typename Stream, typename ...Args>
Stream& print(Stream& o, const Args&... args)
{
    auto x = { ((o << args), 0)... };
    return o;
}
```

This sends all arguments to the stream one at a time while taking the result of the expression after the comma constructing an initializer list of integers.

Comment: Ugh. Phone sucks. Can't Edit. This really should use universal references for `o` and the return type.

Comment: Explaining the `auto x` line a bit further: `x` is a `std::initializer_list<int>`. Braced initializer lists are an allowed context for expanding a parameter pack; the expression `{ (foo args bar)... }` evaluates to `{ (foo arg1 bar), (foo arg2 bar), (foo arg3 bar) }`.   This is useful here because it is guaranteed that items in an initializer list are evaluated from left to right, so the items get sent to `o` in the right order.  The `, 0` is needed to turn the expression's type from `istream&` to `int` because initializer lists cannot contain references.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, it looks even easier than I expected. However I am not sure how to declare the constructor in the header...

Comment: So specifically, no matter how I try, I get errors for using templates in C++ class header file: http://pastebin.com/zWuPHJMM This also happens even when I use inline method declaration.

Comment: What compiler are you using? This solution is for C++11 and newer.