# missing ',' before '...' using variadic template - error in header file

Tags: c++, templates

So I got [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32260692/607407) on my question and I'm trying to get it to work. I modified the original code so that it doesn't take stringstream by parameter, instead it does this:

```
template<typename ...Args>
LineParseException& createLineParseException(const Args&... args);
```

Originally, I was also trying to put it directly in constructor:

```
class LineParseException :
    public std::exception
{
public:
    //The constructor using templates
    template<typename ...Args>
    LineParseException(const Args&... args) {
         std::stringstream o;
         auto x = { ((o << args), 0)... };
         message = o.str();
    }
    ~LineParseException(void);
};
```

I get the very same error for all of the code:

```
1>P\A\T\H\lineparseexception.h(26): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'
```

where line 26 contains:

```
 template<typename ...Args>
```

Comment: I realised I'm in big trouble once I noticed google cannot find that exact error on the whole internet.

Comment: This looks like MSVC. Which version?

Comment: You do have C++11 or higher enabled, right?

Comment: Side note : you probably don't want to use `auto`, which will deduce an `std::initializer_list`, but rather an `int[]`. The latter has defined initializer evaluation order.

Comment: @Quentin Both are fine. The defined order comes from the braces, not the type being initialized.

Comment: So, what is the "original code"? If I just copy all of your code into one file in the right order and try to compile it, everything works perfectly.

Comment: His code is working for me: http://ideone.com/LFg7tE

Comment: No, C++11 doesn't work in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 - or at least  have no idea how to get it to work. Does that mean I should change IDE in order to continue?

Comment: @TomášZato: Visual Studio 2015 Community is free...

Comment: OK, VS2012 doesn't have variadic templates. You'll have to upgrade, stamp out fake variadics (possibly with macros), or change the interface.